# How to compute size of OpenGL's image buffer?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to retrieve OpenGL's color buffer with the following code. My program is crasing in the line that makes the call to **glReadPixels()** apparently `image.data` has not enough memory but how could it be if i'm getting the size from **GL_VIEWPORT** ?

Am I missing something else? I already checked for errors with **glGetError()** and it returns 0 right before the call to glReadPixels.

Any ideas?

```
void GLWidget::readGLBuffer(cv::Mat& image)
{
    GLint vp[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);

    const GLint& cols = vp[2];
    const GLint& rows = vp[3];

    if (rows * cols <= 0)
        return;

    image = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC3);

    glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT); // glReadPixels reads the back buffer by default
    glReadPixels(vp[0], vp[1], cols, rows, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
}
```

Comment: Check if your `Mat` is continuous in memory and not strided by using the `isContinuous` flag. Maybe OpenCV allocates extra bytes for padding, that's why it's running short?. Also check this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097756/converting-data-from-glreadpixels-to-opencvmat

Comment: @gallickgunner thanks a ton it was indeed a problem with cv::Mat and glPixelStorei, your link was really helpful, how can I mark this as answered or make it point to the link?

Comment: Just quote part or whole of the answer and post the link and mark it yourself :)